# Pytorch dataloader Transforms tensor error

Tags: python, pytorch, image-preprocessing, dataloader

[[image: The dataset class][1]][image: The transforms applied to the image]Unable to access the pytorch dataloader values for use
TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, NumPy arrays, numbers, dicts, or lists; found object

The error can be reproduced by running https://jovian.ml/pravin-bnmit/cxr/ on Kaggle
[image]

Comment: I guess it would be beneficial if you share more of the code. it is really hard to guess what the problem is. My guess is that the image is not being converted to tensor (info: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html)

Comment: I have added the code and the notebook is available at https://jovian.ml/pravin-bnmit/cxr/

Comment: the erros in the notebook and in the image you shared here are different. did ToTensor solve your problem? (dataloaders are not subscriptiable, you can do `next(dl)` to load the next batch or simply `for data in dl: do something with data`)

Comment: @VictorZuanazzi
  The error is with the for loop when I try to access the data from dl 
That is giving the error shown above 
You can check the notebook 
I have updated it

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `img = img.resize((1024, 1024))` before the transformation inside the **getitem**() method?

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    row = self.df.loc[idx]
    img_id, img_label = row['Image Index'], row['disease_vec']
    img_fname = row['path']
    img = Image.open(img_fname)
    img = img.resize((1024, 1024))
    if self.transform:
        img = self.transform(img)
    return img, img_label
```

Comment: The problem is that it returns a tuple when exiting from the dataset class. which is an object and the for loop wants to access the 2 tensors which it is not able to causing the error